# How to execute system stored procedure with entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, transactions, system

I call a stored procedure from EF that itself executes a system stored procedure.

```
public virtual int MyFunctionImport()
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("MyFunction"); //calls a sql server system procedure
}
```

Now I get an error because EF wraps transactions around the function execution:

> The procedure cannot be executed within a transaction.

What can be done to get around this problem?

Comment: If you've imported your stored procedure in EF, and function mapped it, then you don't need to execute it with ExecuteFunction - you can just use it like this: `return this.ObjectContext.up_MyStoredProcedure(someparameter)` ... does this still cause the same error when executed this way?

Comment: I cannot build the command, get error: "dbContext does not contain a definition for ObjectContext"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems transactions cannot be turned off as this is EF default behaviour.

```
TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOptions.Suppress)
```

did not help.

I used [bcp service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to "outsource" the system stored procedure in my own stored procedure.

```
select @cmd = 'bcp "EXEC [//insert db name here].[sys].[//insert system procedure name here]" queryout "//insert folder name here"';                
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Easier solutions are appreciated.